# umask setting changes after cd

Tags: linux, redhat, umask

I've got something odd to report.  On my newly configured RHEL5 server my shell is set to /bin/bash I have umask set to 002 in .bashrc.

When I first log in, umask appears to work correctly:

```
$ touch a
$ ls -l a
-rw-rw-r-- etc.....
```

if I create another file it works:

```
$ touch b
$ ls -l b
-rw-rw-r-- etc.....
```

but... if I change directory (to any directory), then umask gets set back 022:

```
$ cd /var/www/whatever
$ touch c
$ ls -l c
-rw-r--r-- etc.....
```

completely bizarre.

Anybody seen anything like this?  Can they think of anything to check?

why would the umask setting change after cd'ing?

Thanks,

-Charlie

Comment: Is it possibly a side effect of the `/var/www/whatever` directory being setgid? Normally that only affects the gid of the created file, but I guess there might be an optional security module that would make it also tweak the umask. Do an `ls -ld` of the directory that is showing the weird effect.

Comment: Have you checked your `alias` settings?

Comment: I found [this](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2010/05/msg01146.html) Debian mailing list message where someone suggested making setgid directories have an effect on the umask. It was shot down, but then it was mentioned that an ACL could be used to achieve the desired effect. Run `getfacl /var/www/whatever` to find out if that is the cause.

Comment: Unfortunately it's happening in any directory.  For instance: if I touch to create a file in my home directory, right after logging in, it will have the correct permissions. If I cd somewhere else (anywhere) then cd back to home (same directory I created the first file), and touch to create another file, it comes up rw-r--r--.

Comment: if I set umask in /etc/profile I get the desired behavior... but i'm still mystified as to why this was a problem

Comment: Maybe it's your home directory that has a special ACL. `getfacl $HOME`

Comment: yes, that might be it:


user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

Comment: I asked the question on the [Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47872/umask-changes-to-0002-after-cd) site and we found something interesting. Have you installed RVM to get Ruby on Rails? It has taken control of your `cd` command. Entering `type cd` will show you what's actually going on.

Comment: only ACL and SGID cause this problem.

Comment: The umask does not change. Run umask without arguments and you will see that it is the same. Unless it is overridden by your /etc/profile (or some such) in the new terminals you start after reading .bashrc in the original terminal.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Barry Brown for the comment above - I was tearing my hair out with this problem (on OSX, not Linux) and it is indeed rvm that was the culprit in my case. 
Check your .profile, .bash_profile etc for a line like this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment it out, relaunch your shell and that should solve the problem.
I had no idea rvm was so rude and intrusive. Better to load it only when needed rather than for every shell.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: the umask has four digits and it does not change arbitrarily, but /etc/profile and fiends will set it to 022 by default;

**update**
I kinda got carried away with this and forgot to properly answer your question:

Check that the partition (if any) mounted on the folder where you change to, does not have a umask set. (just type **mount**)

The long answer is:

**man chmod**
§6:
A numeric mode is from one to four octal digits (0-7), derived by adding up
the bits with values 4, 2, and 1. Omitted digits are assumed to be leading 
zeros. The first digit selects the set user ID (4) and set group ID (2) and 
restricted deletion or sticky (1) attributes. The second digit selects 
permissions for the user who owns the file: read (4), write (2), and execute 
(1); the third selects permissions for other users in the file's group, with 
the same values; and the fourth for other users not in the file's group, with 
the same values.

GNU coreutils 8.14 October 2011

---

I remember reading this man page several times some years back, and never 
quite understanding what all of this means before I set up a table. Since I've
lost my reference table, I'll recreate it here. Since I don't like the symbolic
notation becasue it is more cumbersome to type (e.g chmod u+x), I'll leave out 
any mention of it.

---

## Interpretation of **chmod** and **umask**

Possible setting:
4: read
2: write
1: execute

### Possible values of each digit with examples

```
domain  setuid  user    group   world
digit   1       2       3       4
values  0-7     0-7     0-7     0-7
```

The `possible setting' values in the curly braces {} may be 
summed together to produce a valid permission bit (number).

**Common examples**

*0755*: The user may enter a folder and write (remove) files in that folder
        If this mask is set on a file, the the user may execute the file (i.e.
        ./filenme.bin). The last two digits mean that the group to which the 
        file belongs and the world (anyone else on the system), may execute 
        the file as well. Applied to direcotories it means that the group and 
        world may enter that directory.

*0644*: User may read and write a file, but not execute it. Group and world 
        may only read the file. Applied to a folder, this mask wil prevent 
        anyone from entering that directory.

*0600*: Only the owner may read and write a file with this mask

*0700*: Only the owner of a folder may enter, read and write the contents of a 
        folder with this mask.

*0000*: Useful for "hiding" files or for signaling (to yourself) that a file
        or a folder is not supposed to be used.

**Meaningless masks**

*0200*: If a user can write a file, then they may also alter the umask of a file.

**Dangerous masks**

*0666*: Everyone can read, write to and delete a file with this mask

*0777*: Same thing for a folder. If a binary file is set *777*, then anyone can put
        anything they want into that file and run it, even if it is in the system-
        wide binaries directory such as /usr/bin.

*4755*: Binary files owned by the superuser (root) will run with superuser 
        permissions. The implications of this should be clear. Perhaps, counder-
        intuitively setting an interpreted-script with 4755 will have no effect 
        becasue a script (such as a bash script) is still run by /bin/bash. The 
        text file where the script is stored is not really an executable.

In all of the above examples, the leading zero may be omitted for convenience.

### Converting umask to chmod

To set a proper umask, all that needs to be done is subtracting the unwanted 
permissions from the `maximum mask' which by is 0777 for folders and 666 for 
files.

To force the shell to create files with the default permission of 644 set umask to
0022. For folders, the typical (desired) umask might be 755 and is acheived by 
setting the umask to 0022.

```
 0666  0777
-0022 -0022
 ____  ____
 0644  0755
```

---

Relative links:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts